# Alguém sabe uma maneira mais simples de fazer esse efeito, ir aparecendo o texto instantaneamente ao digitar em um input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
  <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="formVal">
<form name="fvalida">
  <input type="text" id="telp" placeholder="">
</form>
<div id="preview_form">
  <div id="telp1"></div>
</div>
  <script>try {jQuery.fn.shake = function(intShakes, intDistance, intDuration) {
  this.each(function() {
    {; for (var x=1000; x<=intShakes; x++) {;
    }}
  });
};

$("#telp").keyup(function(){
  $("#telp1").html($(this).val());
});

} catch (error) { throw error; }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que é que esse código deve fazer? O que queres que ele faça?

Comment: digitar em um input ou textarea e ir aparecendo em uma div instantaneamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usares

```
$("#telp").keyup(function() {
  $("#telp1").html(this.value);
});
```

Se quiseres fazer só com JavaScript nativo podes fazer assim:

```js
var telp = document.getElementById('telp');
var telp1 = document.getElementById('telp1');
telp.addEventListener('input', function() {
  telp1.textContent = this.value;
});
```

```html
<form name="fvalida">
  <input type="text" id="telp" placeholder="">
</form>
<div id="preview_form">
  <div id="telp1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Voltz sua edição foi rejeitada pois as altera características linguísticas que em nada afetam a interpretação do post, além de estarem corretas gramaticamente.

Comment: Muito bom! mas ainda tem uma parte que não consegui implementar que é a quebra do div quando ultrapassar uma quantidades de caracteres e passar para linha abaixo, pq quando vou digitando a div passa da tela do note.

Comment: @ElvisDaCunhaPereira isso é um problema de CSS. Podes resolver de maneiras diferentes, por exemplo com `#telp1{word-wrap: break-word;}`. Mas isso é uma pergunta diferente, caso não encontres resposta podes fazer uma pergunta sobre isso.

Comment: É verdade!! não tinha me atentado a isso.